# Is there any way to do backspace twice to clear a text field using selenium webdriver through C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a text field that contains a 2 digit value by default. I want to clear it before I type a new value. I was using `TextSlider.Clear();` but after the latest ChromeDriver update, it's no longer working so I am trying to workaround it using backspace. Currently I am doing two backspaces, one at a time.

```
TextSlider.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
TextSlider.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
```

I also tried DELETE but that's also not working. Is there any way to do this in a single line?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all,

i have managed to workaround using ctrl A and Delete

```
     TextSlider.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
     TextSlider.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
```

Comment: Or you can do TextSlider.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a', Keys.BACKSPACE)

Answer (score 0):

```
TextSlider.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace + Keys.Backspace);
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to fix like how `TextSlider.Clear();` is not working. There might me loading issue, SendKeys method will work. Try to add wait for page to load properly.

If still not working then you can use,

```
TextSlider.Click();
TextSlider.Clear();
```

But below functionality will definatly work,

```
TextSlider.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace + Keys.Backspace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Keys.Backspace`, ideally to clear a *text field* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using [`ElementToBeClickable Method (IWebElement)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(TextSlider)).Clear();
  ```
- Using [`ElementToBeClickable Method (By)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm):

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(By.CssSelector("css_TextSlider")).Clear();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to clear the text element by using Javascript. Due to issues occurring in certain parallel testing situations, I stopped relying on the SendKeys function some time ago. Instead, I use these functions now to set a certain text:

```
    private void SetText(IWebElement element, string text, bool clearOldText)
    {
        // Clear old text if needed
        if (clearOldText)
        {
            LogInfo("Clearing " + element.ToString() + @" from any text.");
            SetElementValue(element, "");
        }

        element.Click();
        SetElementValue(element, text);
    }

    public string SetElementValue(IWebElement element, string value)
    {
        ScrollToElement(element);
        PaintElement(element, "yellow");
        var exec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)this;
        var script = @"
            var el = arguments[0];
            el.value = '" + value + @"';
            try 
            {
                if (""createEvent"" in document) {
                    var evt = document.createEvent(""HTMLEvents"");
                            evt.initEvent(""change"", false, true);
                            el.dispatchEvent(evt);
                        }
                else
                    el.fireEvent(""onchange"");
            }
            catch(err){ return err; }
            return ""Javascript executed."";
            ";
        LogInfo("Setting value to '" + value + "' for " + element.ToString());
        var result = exec.ExecuteScript(script, element);
        Recorder?.AddScreenshot();
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Personally I dislike the hardcoded javascript a bit, but it always did the job reliably. "SetElementValue" is called twice in this code to ensure correct handling of certain events in my tests: it might not be necessary in other cases.